# Positioning view to the right of a sidebar with Rails/Bootstrap layout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-4

I'm building a web app using Rails 5.2 and Bootstrap 4 and I'm having some trouble getting the basic layout in place.

What I'd like is to move the content for each view to the right of the sidebar. i.e. "Your companies".

Can someone help point me in the right direction so that all my views are "inside" the app view i.e below the nav and to the right of the sidebar.

Thank you! :)

Here's how the app looks currently:

[image]

Here is my **application.html.erb**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Calmcap</title>
      <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
      <%= csp_meta_tag %>
      <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
      <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
      <!-- TODO add these as assets -->
      <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
      <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
      <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="container">
         <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Calmcap</a>
            <p class="navbar-text pull-right">
               <% if user_signed_in? %>
               Userid: <%= current_user.id %> / Logged in as <strong><%= current_user.email %></strong>.
               <%= link_to 'Edit profile', edit_user_registration_path, :class => 'navbar-link' %> |
               <%= link_to "Logout", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete, :class => 'navbar-link'  %>
               <% else %>
               <%= link_to "Sign up", new_user_registration_path, :class => 'navbar-link'  %> |
               <%= link_to "Login", new_user_session_path, :class => 'navbar-link'  %>
               <% end %>
            </p>
         </nav>
         <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3 sidebar">
               <div class="mini-submenu">
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
               </div>
               <div class="list-group">
                  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                  <i class="fa fa-comment-o"></i> Lorem ipsum
                  </a>
                  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                  <i class="fa fa-search"></i> Lorem ipsum
                  </a>
                  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                  <i class="fa fa-user"></i> Lorem ipsum
                  </a>
                  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                  <i class="fa fa-folder-open-o"></i> Lorem ipsum <span class="badge">14</span>
                  </a>
                  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                  <i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o"></i> Lorem ipsumr <span class="badge">14</span>
                  </a>
                  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                  <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> Lorem ipsum
                  </a>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <% if notice %>
      <p class="alert alert-success"><%= notice %></p>
      <% end %>
      <% if alert %>
      <p class="alert alert-danger"><%= alert %></p>
      <% end %>
      <div class="span10">
         <!--Body content-->
         <%= yield %>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

And here is my `companies` view (the same as the example in the screenshot above).

```
<div class="container">
   <h1>Your Companies</h1>
   <button>
   <%= link_to 'Create New Company', new_company_path %>
   </button>
   <table>
      <tr>
         <th>Title</th>
         <th>Text</th>
         <th></th>
      </tr>
      <% @companies.each do |company| %>
      <tr>
         <td><%= company.title %></td>
         <td><%= company.text %></td>
         <td><%= link_to 'View Company', company_path(company) %></td>
         <td><%= link_to 'Edit Company', edit_company_path(company) %></td>
         <td><%= link_to 'Delete Company', company_path(company),
            method: :delete,
            data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
      <% end %>
   </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want to do something like that:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Calmcap</title>
      <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
      <%= csp_meta_tag %>
      <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
      <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
      <!-- TODO add these as assets -->
      <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
      <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
      <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="container">
         <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Calmcap</a>
            <p class="navbar-text pull-right">
               <% if user_signed_in? %>
               Userid: <%= current_user.id %> / Logged in as <strong><%= current_user.email %></strong>.
               <%= link_to 'Edit profile', edit_user_registration_path, :class => 'navbar-link' %> |
               <%= link_to "Logout", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete, :class => 'navbar-link'  %>
               <% else %>
               <%= link_to "Sign up", new_user_registration_path, :class => 'navbar-link'  %> |
               <%= link_to "Login", new_user_session_path, :class => 'navbar-link'  %>
               <% end %>
            </p>
         </nav>
         <div class="row">
            <% if notice %>
              <p class="alert alert-success"><%= notice %></p>
            <% end %>
            <% if alert %>
             <p class="alert alert-danger"><%= alert %></p>
            <% end %>
            <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3 sidebar">
               <div class="mini-submenu">
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
               </div>
               <div class="list-group">
                  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                  <i class="fa fa-comment-o"></i> Lorem ipsum
                  </a>
                  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                  <i class="fa fa-search"></i> Lorem ipsum
                  </a>
                  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                  <i class="fa fa-user"></i> Lorem ipsum
                  </a>
                  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                  <i class="fa fa-folder-open-o"></i> Lorem ipsum <span class="badge">14</span>
                  </a>
                  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                  <i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o"></i> Lorem ipsumr <span class="badge">14</span>
                  </a>
                  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                  <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> Lorem ipsum
                  </a>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-9">
               <!--Body content-->
              <%= yield %>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>

   </body>
</html>
```

Also, remove the class `container` from your `companies/index.html.erb` file.

Comment: This worked great. Will check the diff so I see what you did there. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to hear that. Anyways, better if you check the bootstrap grid layout. It'll help you to find what I did there. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

As you are using **bootstrap 4**, you should use `float-right` class to float the content to the right.

```
<div class="container float-right">
  --------content--------
</div
```

More info [*here*](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/float/)